# Как можно отправить запрос определенному устройству за роутером?

Tags: python, маршрутизация

Есть компьютер (далее роутер) с белым ip адресом. В его сети есть несколько устройств.
Пользователь должен подключиться к конкретному устройству в локальной сети роутера. Роутер служит чем то вроде прокси.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для одного устройства в сети я просто прослушивал порт и пересылал все что приходило на одно устройство (код ниже), а вот если в локалке устройств несколько, я не понимаю как на них перенаправлять

```
import socket
import select
import time
import sys


buffer_size = 4096
delay = 0.0001
forward_to = ('192.168.1.233', 8000)


class Forward:

    def __init__(self):
        self.forward = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def start(self, host, port):
        try:
            self.forward.connect((host, port))
            return self.forward

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False


class TheServer:
    input_list = []
    channel = {}

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.bind((host, port))
        self.server.listen(200)

    def main_loop(self):
        self.input_list.append(self.server)
        while 1:
            time.sleep(delay)
            ss = select.select
            inputready, outputready, exceptready = ss(self.input_list, [], [])

            for self.s in inputready:
                if self.s == self.server:
                    self.on_accept()
                    break
                self.data = self.s.recv(buffer_size)

                if len(self.data) == 0:
                    self.on_close()
                    break

                else:
                    self.on_recv()

    def on_accept(self):
        forward = Forward().start(forward_to[0], forward_to[1])
        clientsock, clientaddr = self.server.accept()

        if forward:
            print(clientaddr, "has connected")
            self.input_list.append(clientsock)
            self.input_list.append(forward)
            self.channel[clientsock] = forward
            self.channel[forward] = clientsock

        else:
            print("Can't establish connection with remote server.")
            print("Closing connection with client side", clientaddr)
            clientsock.close()

    def on_close(self):
        print(self.s.getpeername(), "has disconnected")

        #remove objects from input_list
        self.input_list.remove(self.s)
        self.input_list.remove(self.channel[self.s])
        out = self.channel[self.s]

        # close the connection with client
        self.channel[out].close()  # equivalent to do self.s.close()

        # close the connection with remote server
        self.channel[self.s].close()

        # delete both objects from channel dict
        del self.channel[out]
        del self.channel[self.s]

    def on_recv(self):
        data = self.data

        # here we can parse and/or modify the data before send forward
        print(data)
        self.channel[self.s].send(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        server = TheServer('', 9090)
        try:
            server.main_loop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Ctrl C - Stopping server")
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Ну пересылка, как я понимаю, идёт безусловно на `forward_to = ('192.168.1.233', 8000)`. Если так, то какая разница, есть ли в сети ещё компьютеры с другими адресами? Или надо то на один форвардить, то на другой? тогда входящие пакеты должны иметь некий признак, позволяющий понять, куда пересылать... например, это может быть номер порта, на который пришёл пакет на внешний интерфейс роутера.

Comment: @Akina нужно отслылать то на один то на другой. Порт, к сожалению, на внешнем интерфейсе может быть только один, и вот как в пакете по другому указать путь, я не знаю

Comment: Да Вы сперва решите, как определять, на какой из внутренних девайсов надо слать пришедший пакет.... и только потом думайте, как это реализовывать. *Порт, к сожалению, на внешнем интерфейсе может быть только один* А это почему? странно как-то... Вы же делаете привязку `self.server.bind` - ну в крайнем случае будет 4 отдельных сервера, каждый со своим значением параметра `port`, и каждый будет форвардить на своё устройство.